# Transferring data from a react hook to an array of objects

Tags: react-hooks, react-chartjs

Encountered a problem when using react-charts. To draw a graph, you need an array of objects similar to the data:

```
data: [
  { "x": new Date("2020.03.18"), "y": 60 },
  { "x": new Date("2020.03.19"),"y": 23 },
  { "x": new Date("2020.03.20"),"y": 23 }
]
```

My data is stored in the react hook in this form:
[image]

Here is my failed attempt to split a hook into an array of objects:

```
    const initialState = [
        dataCharts.map((units) => {
            {x: new Date(units.y), y: units.x}
        })
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
dataCharts.map(d => {
  return {
    "x": d.x.split(" ")[0].split(".").reverse().join("."),
    "y": d.y
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. And for react-charts now use it like this?
`         
label: "Series 1",
         datums: [dataCharts.map(d => {
    return {
      "x": new Date(d.x.split(" ")[0].split(".").reverse().join(".")),
      "y": d.y
    }
     })]
`
The graph is not displayed for some reason.

Comment: could you create a sandbox and provide the link so that it will be easy to debug.